# Como imprimir un Ticket muy largo usando PrintDocument

Tags: c#, windows-forms, print

Estoy intentando imprimir un ticket en una impresora termica, la informacion que debe contener el ticket es bastante por lo que el ticket tiene un largo considerable.
Estoy utilizando un objeto PrintDocument para imprimir el ticket, en el evento PrintPage utilizo un objeto Graphics para escribir toda la informacion.
Al imprimirse el ticket aparece correctamente, el problema es que no se imprime completo.
Existe alguna forma para indicar el tamaño de la impresion y que asi pueda imprimirse completo el ticket?

```
PrintDocument printDocument = new PrintDocument();
        printDocument.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = impresora;            
        printDocument.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(this.pr_PrintPage);
        printDocument.Print();
```

Este es el evento PrintPage:

```
    private void pr_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Millimeter;            
        this.gfx = e.Graphics;
        this.DrawHeader();
        this.DrawItems();
        this.DrawTotales();
        this.DrawFooter();            
    }
```

para las metodos de "Draw" estoy utilizando la funcion DrawString del objeto Graphics (gfx).

Answer (score 1):

Puedes especificar el tamaño de la pàgina a imprimir indicando el `PaperSize` en la propiedad `DefaultPageSettings` de `PrinterSettings` de la siguiente forma:

```
int width = 100; //Indicar el ancho de la pàgina
int height = 100; //Indicar el alto de la pàgina

PrintDocument printDocument = new PrintDocument();
printDocument.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = impresora;
printDocument.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = new PaperSize("Nombre a poner a esta configuración", width, height);
printDocument.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(this.pr_PrintPage);
printDocument.Print();
```

Comment: Tenia esa idea, pero necesito obtener el height de la informacion que voy a imprimir, porque no siempre es del mismo tamaño, necesito ver como obtengo ese valor del objeto Graphics

Comment: @JuanAlberto Añade en la pregunta como construyes la impresión (el método pr_PrintPage

Comment: Probé asignando el tamaño de papel a un tamaño determinado pero la impresión sigue saliendo incompleta.
Ya agregue el evento PrintPage en el post original.

Answer (score 0):

Para saber cuanto te va a ocupar el texto que vas a imprimir, utiliza el método `MeasureString` del objecto `graphics`, y podrás acceder a las propiedades de tamaño:

```
g.MeasureString("TEXTO", font).Width
```